# Should I send a PDF or Google Drive link to professors?

Tags: cv, email, international-students

To avoid the spam filter by Gmail, should I directly attach my CV in PDF format or should I upload my CV in Google Drive and put the Google Drive link at the end of my email?

I heard PDFs that contains links (I have so many links in my CV) usually go to  the spam folder. Do you think putting a Google Drive link is the best option to send my CV to professors?

Comment: Who knows how university Spam filters work. Some would block drive links, some would block PDFs, some both some neither. I am not sure there is an answer to this that would work generally

Comment: I think the problem is that you have many links in your CV. Are they links to papers ? If yes, why not use DOIs ?

Comment: @Nobody not just doi, I gave links to the journals linking the dois, moever, I link to every Institutes and every references.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but I would remove the full URL for doi and just do `doi:[whatever] `. It's nicer to look at, gets the same point across, and avoids this issue entirely. This is also how I've usually seen doi presented in CVs.

Comment: Fairly typical safety policy these days is that you are not supposed to click on any link from people you don't know. Yeah, some don't follow it, but what if the person receiving your CV does?

Comment: I hope you are not cold-sending your CV to people without having made contact first. (Academics get tons of emails from people that want to work in their lab. Most such cold emails end up in the trash, because most senders are just spamming hundreds of academics without investing the time to tailor their applications.) And now, if you have first established some contact with your recipient and exchanged a few emails before sending out your CV, the spam filter should be aware that you are a trusted contact by the time it sees your PDF CV.

Comment: Incidentally, I beg to differ with the common advice here not to use DOI links in PDFs. It is getting far to easy to generate impressive-sounding papers with LLMs (be it for a CV, or as "references" for a piece of academic work), many of which are [hallucinations or entirely off-topic](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/chatgpt-generator-mindless-bullshit-stephan-kolassa/). Links you can click on is the only time-efficient way to figure out whether a reference even exists, or is relevant. I have been recommending to only accept theses with such links.

Comment: @StephanKolassa In my opinion it is good to keep CV as simple as possible. It is sufficient to provide just 2 links to profiles at orcid.org and scholar.google.com. Links to papers and institutions can be included into the profile information.

Comment: If your emails land in the spam filter of the people you send it to, it may be an indication that what you are sending is spam. Many institutions have processes in place for hiring PhD students that do not involve you emailing individual professors. In that case you should follow the procedure outlined on their websites and all emails to individuals are just spam.

Comment: @StephanKolassa if you click on any link provided in a CV, you can as well spend the time manually looking in your favoured search engine for the impressive papers referenced in the CV: you spend marginally more time (copy&paste in google instead of clicking on the link, the time spent to read the abstract is then the same) and you have a first check on the quality (your brain start to understand where the paper is published etcetc).

Comment: A Google Drive link would strike me as odd and would not count in your favor if you emailed me.

Answer (score 34):

I'm wary of PDFs with embedded links that have been sent by someone unknown to me. And on principle, I wouldn't download something from a Google drive in such a situation.

Attach a PDF without embedded links. The links' value to the recipient is small at best but they might get your email moved to a spam filter or discarded manually as a potential phishing attack.

Comment: Fully agree, the simpler---the better. Some companies (maybe not universities) automatise the information extraction from CVs. PDF should be machine comprehendible or will be neglected.

Comment: I doubt an email with a link would even get through the filter at the university I did my PhD at. Spammers constantly targeted my professor (and head of the department), and the spam filter was accordingly set very strict. Even my email gets spammed constantly (often by people pretending to be him).

Comment: I have never heard of people objecting to a PDF containing links. It sounds no different to objecting to a webpage containing links (i.e. no risk whatsoever, unless you have a severely compromised PDF reader). Is this really a widespread belief?

Comment: @preferred_anon https://www.trustwave.com/en-us/resources/blogs/spiderlabs-blog/threat-loaded-malicious-pdfs-never-go-out-of-style/

Comment: @Roland Everything in the "Malicious Hyperlinks" section applies verbatim to any link in a web browser. I considered facetiously saying "sorry, I can't read that article due to my security policy", but realised that according to the advice I should never have even visited this page for fear of it containing a malicious link. I'm not trying to be silly, by the way. I just suspect that users do not need to be as scared as you suggest.

Comment: @preferred_anon That may well be but the fact of the matter is that they are cautious. Being not an expert in IT security myself I prefer to err on the site of caution. When I consider applications I see no value in any embedded links.

Comment: @Roland Isn't the benefit obvious? My CV (for example) has links to my personal website, references to articles written, websites for projects I've contributed to, and so on. As far as I know, people rely on this sort of thing in electronic documents all the time. The alternative is copy-pasting or even typing out the URL into an address bar (which is actually equally risky). And of course nobody forces you to click them - if you do want to err on the side of caution, never click any links. After all it would be most cautious to switch off your computer and never open any email.

Comment: @preferred_anon PDFs may have fonts embedded, and fonts are a big problem (see e.g. [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/project-zero/issues/detail?id=2131) and [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91347/how-can-a-font-be-used-for-privilege-escalation)). Not trusting PDFs from unknown sources is a smart move. Alas, that applies to both embedded links and attached files, but at least attached files may be scanned as a part of a broader security policy.

Comment: The key point is never trust anything at all that shows up randomly out of the blue. .DOC and .XLS files are almost always malicious. .HTML files sent as email attachments are always malicious. PDFs are about 50% malicious, so you can't really block all of them, but absolutely you should be suspicious if you suddenly get a PDF from someone you don't know.

Answer (score 8):

Reiterating other answers and comments: PDF without links. Everything else has some security dangers. The links do not add so much...

Answer (score 4):

- if you are sending an email to a professor, it should be to their university email so gmail’s spam policies are irrelevant.
- I’ve sent a few pdfs with links in it to university emails and all were received properly, so I’d say go for it!

Comment: There is a flaw in your thinking: many university emails are powered by the biggest advertising company in the world. As an example, see https://bconnected.berkeley.edu/collaboration-services/google/bmail

Comment: I disagree with the first claim in this generality. I much prefer any email not strictly about university-related stuff to go to my gmail rather than my university email. This includes most research related stuff.

Comment: @EarlGrey Even some large multinational corporations do the same, despite the fact that they could afford setting up their own e-mail servers. Apparently data privacy is only a part of their sales speeches...

Comment: @EarlGrey's right, and when you add in those who have outsourced their email to Microsoft, it might be a minority that still run their own mailservers

Comment: @TrangOul I work for a midsize firm, that should be able to afford internal tools, I am a victim of such a system (accounting system by one of the big providers). 2 years into the change from our own system to the new system and we still are fixing stuff instead of reaping the benefits from the new system.
I wonder company must do,  because the big providers offer the iso/whatever certifications with their softwares, so then the investors can do "due diligence" by simply checking formalities when needed (i.e. 2 times, before investing and before selling) , instead of doing proper checks ...

Comment: Large institutions using Google for their email are not using generic gmail accounts. They're using customized environments with admin controls over filtering and such, assuming they are competent.

Comment: @barbecue the admin controls are often just a smoke in the eye and the customization is quite limited. Alphabet and Google can be very untransparent when they are in for business, see Google Scholar ...

Answer (score 3):

You could also send the pdf along with a second, follow up, mail after a day or so saying that you have sent the earlier mail and asking if it was received. You could instead and more simply, in the first mail, ask for a brief reply that it has been received.

Comment: "You could instead and more simply, in the first mail, ask for a brief reply that it has been received." While you could do that, it not particularly likely you would get  a reply.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on who you send this to.

If they **expect an email** from you I would go for a link, ideally to a page (google docs style), and to a PDF as a second option.
**Why?** Because the online content can be changed as needed (possibly with versioning) but when you attach a document it is gone. And you must the rely on filenames such as `article-V2-reviewed-draft-v4-final-reviewed-reallyfinal.pdf`

If this is **cold emailing** and they do not expect your email I would send an introduction paragraph mentioning that the article is in the body of the email and as an attachment for their convenience.
**Why?** Because nowadays everyone avoids clicking around.